# DOCX4J conditional paragaph update merge FieldUpdater Does not work

Tags: merge, conditional-statements, docx4j

Using a legacy IF field code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFapJ.png)

and content controls:

```
private static byte[] mergingDocxFileWithXml(File file, File fileXml) {WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file)
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart()
        ArrayList<String> datas
        List<Object> contentControls = ContentControl.getAllContentControl(mainDocumentPart)
        List<String> arrayListXpathToBoucle = new ArrayList<>()

        for (Object contenControl : contentControls) {
            ContentControl cControl = new ContentControl(contenControl)
            String xPath = cControl.getXPath()
            String title = cControl.getTitle()

            if (xPath != null) {
                datas = XmlPath.getXmlDataFrom(fileXml, xPath)
            }

            switch (title) {

                case "DateDuJour":
                    cControl.setValue(getDateDay())
                    break

                case "checkbox":
                    String checkValue = new String(Character.toChars(0x2612))
                    if (datas[0] != "1") {
                        checkValue = new String(Character.toChars(0x2610))
                    }
                    cControl.setValue(checkValue)
                    break
                case "Boucle_Ligne":
                    xPath = cControl.getTag()

                    int indexBoucleContent = getIndexContentBoucle(wordMLPackage.mainDocumentPart.getContent(), xPath)

                    NodeList nodeList = XmlPath.getNodeListXmlFile(fileXml, xPath)

                    List<String> dataXpath = getAllXpathForBoucle(contentControls, xPath)
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataXpath.stream().count(); i++) {
                        arrayListXpathToBoucle.add(dataXpath.get(i))
                    }
                    int totalNode = nodeList.getLength()


                    for (int j = 0; j < totalNode; j++) {
                        wordMLPackage = mapingDataNode(j, cControl, contentControls, fileXml, dataXpath, wordMLPackage, indexBoucleContent, null, 0)
                    }

                    wordMLPackage.mainDocumentPart.getContent().remove(indexBoucleContent)
                    break;
                case "Boucle_Colonne":
                    xPath = cControl.getTag()
                    NodeList nodeList = XmlPath.getNodeListXmlFile(fileXml, xPath)
                    List<String> dataXpath = getAllXpathForBoucle(contentControls, xPath)
                    int totalNode = nodeList.getLength()
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataXpath.stream().count(); i++) {
                        arrayListXpathToBoucle.add(dataXpath.get(i))
                    }
                    String boucleValue = ""
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalNode; i++) {
                        datas = XmlPath.getXmlDataFrom(fileXml, dataXpath.get(0))
                        boucleValue += datas.get(i) + ", "
                    }
                    boucleValue = boucleValue.substring(0, boucleValue.length() - 2)
                    addValueInContentControl(contentControls, dataXpath.get(0), 0, boucleValue, null, wordMLPackage)
                    break
                case "Boucle_Ligne_Table":
                    xPath = cControl.getTag()

                    NodeList nodeList = XmlPath.getNodeListXmlFile(fileXml, xPath)
                    int indexBoucleContent = getIndexContentBoucle(wordMLPackage.mainDocumentPart.getContent(), xPath)
                    List<String> dataXpath = getAllXpathForBoucle(contentControls, xPath)
                    int totalNode = nodeList.getLength()

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataXpath.stream().count(); i++) {
                        arrayListXpathToBoucle.add(dataXpath.get(i))
                    }

                    int nodeIndex = 0

                    Tbl arraysBoucle = getArraysBoucle(wordMLPackage, indexBoucleContent)
                    Tr trContent

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalNode; i++) {
                        nodeIndex = i + 1
                        if (arraysBoucle.getContent().stream().count() > 1) {
                            trContent = WoeDocx4jFunction.getTr(arraysBoucle.getContent().get(1))
                        } else {
                            trContent = WoeDocx4jFunction.getTr(arraysBoucle.getContent().get(0))
                        }

                        wordMLPackage = mapingDataNode(i, cControl, contentControls, fileXml, dataXpath, wordMLPackage, indexBoucleContent, trContent, nodeIndex)
                    }
                    int lastIndexTr = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().get(indexBoucleContent).sdtContent.content.get(1).value.content.stream().count()
                    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().get(indexBoucleContent).sdtContent.content.get(1).value.content.remove(lastIndexTr - 1)
                    break
                case "IMAGE":
                    datas = XmlPath.getXmlDataFrom(fileXml, xPath)
                    byte[] imageByte = base64ToImage(datas.get(0))
                    Inline inlineImage = newImage(wordMLPackage, imageByte)
                    cControl.setValue(null, inlineImage)
                    break
                default:
                    String xpathBoucle = arrayListXpathToBoucle.find { it.startsWith(xPath) }
                    if (xpathBoucle != xPath) {
                      addValueInContentControl(contentControls, xPath, 0, "", fileXml,wordMLPackage)
                    }
                    break
            }
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        wordMLPackage=  mergingFieldWordMlPackage(wordMLPackage)
        FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(wordMLPackage)
        updater.update(true);
        wordMLPackage.save(outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Qui peut m'aider s'il-vous-plait je suis dans l'urgence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Docx4j's legacy field processing does not parse IF fields: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/IF.html

If you need to do that, you'll need to write code to do the parsing.

An alternative would be to use OpenDoPE conditional content controls.  With one of these, the content of the SDT is included only if the associated XPath evaluates to true.

Comment: My problem is updating the document. To see the information I have to right click and update the fields. I want it to be automatic in the code